# skip a condition if the condition value is null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning mongoDB and had this problem. I want to filter out the list of books I want using the filter below. If the author, category, and status values are not null, all three conditions will be met, and when one or two values are null, it will be omitted from the condition and filtered by valid conditions.

```
const { status, genre, author } = req.body;
  console.log(status, genre, author)

const listBook = await MODEL_BOOKS.find({

      $and: [
        { author: { $in: author } },
        { genre: { $in: genre } },
        { status: status }
      ]
    })
    return res.status(200).send({ data: listBook })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your custom `filter` array based on the conditions specified:

```
const { status, genre, author } = req.body;
console.log(status, genre, author);

const filter = [];
if (status) filter.push({ status: status });
if (genre) filter.push({ genre: { $in: genre } });
if (author) filter.push({ author: { $in: author } });

const listBook = await MODEL_BOOKS.find({
  $and: filter,
});

return res.status(200).send({ data: listBook });
```

Comment: Sincerely thank you! It worked exactly what I expected.